# Extension field adjointing a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $K/k$ an extension field. Consider $A\subseteq K$ and $u\in k(A)$. Prove that exists elements $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\in A$ such that $u\in k(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$.

I've proved that $k\subseteq k(A)\subseteq K$ and I think thta exists a basis of $k(A)$, over $k$ such that $\beta\subseteq A$, and thus conclude. Any help? or another argument?

Comment: Existence of the basis $\beta \subseteq A$ is sufficient to conclude.

Comment: I know, and the existence is ensured by Zorn's Lemma but why I can supose that $\beta\subseteq A$, maybe is a dumb question but I can figure that argumment

Comment: $u \in k(A)$ is a rational function in the elements of $A$ with coefficients in $k$.  The numerator and denominator of such a rational function only have finitely many terms, hence only use finitely many elements of $A$.

Comment: You can prove it using the same argument as in "every vector space has a basis" by using Zorn's Lemma on the set $\{ B \subseteq A : B$ is linearly independent over $k\}.$

Comment: I don't need for use that "rational construction" that k(A) or instance $K$ are finite extensions? For example $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm pretty sure that $k(A) = \left\{\frac{f(a_1, \ldots, a_n)}{g(a_1, \ldots, a_n)} : n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}, f,g \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n], a_1, \ldots a_n \in A \ \right\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof will depend on which definition of $k(A)$ you are using.  My definition is $k(A)$ is the intersection of all subfields of $K$ which contain $k$ and $A$.

Let $F$ be the set of elements of $K$ of the form

$$\frac{f(a_1, ... , a_n)}{g(a_1, ... , a_n)}$$

where $n \geq 1$; $a_1, ... , a_n \in A$; $f, g \in k[T_1, ... , T_n]$; and $g(a_1, ... , a_n) \neq 0$.

It is easy to see that $F$ is contained in every subfield of $K$ which contains $k$ and $A$.  This is because such a subfield must be closed under addition, multiplication, and division.  Therefore, $F \subseteq k(A)$.

On the other hand, $F$ is itself a subfield of $K$ containing both $k$ and $A$.  Therefore, $F$ appears as one of the subfields in the intersection defining $k(A)$.  So, $k(A) \subseteq F$.

Then $k(A) = F$, and from this description of $k(A)$, it is obvious that

$$k(A) = \bigcup\limits_{E \subseteq A \textrm{ finite}} k(E)$$

In particular, if $u \in k(A)$, then $u$ is is in some $k(E)$, for some $E = \{a_1, ... , a_n\}$.  The usual notation is

$$k(\{a_1, ... , a_n\}) = k(a_1, ... , a_n)$$